# sending email with nodemailer version 2.0

Tags: node.js, smtp, nodemailer

I want to send email from localhost with nodemailer. Function to send email is below

```
sendEmail : function(toEmail, subjek, param){
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
        host : "smtp.gmail.com",
        port : 465,
        secure : true, 
        ignoreTLS : true,
        auth : {
            username : config.userMail,
            password : config.passMail
        }
    template = fs.readFileSync('public/views/emailTemplate/token.hjs','utf-8'),
    compiledTemplate = Hogan.compile(template);

// setup e-mail data with unicode symbols
var mailOptions = {
    from: 'User', // sender address
    to: toEmail, // list of receivers
    subject: subjek, // Subject line
    html: compiledTemplate.render(param)
};

// send mail with defined transport object
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){

     if(error){
         return error
     }else{
         return info         
     }
});
```

}

if I call the function, it is return `undefined`. I don't have any idea whic part is missing or error
How do I fix it?

Comment: You can't use `return` from an asynchronous callback function, at least not in a meaningful way. Using `return` stops the function but there's nowhere to return the value to.

Comment: I try to send a respon like this.
 if(error) res.send(error):

But it gives me error "Can't sent header after they are sent"

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I do not have enough reputation to make comment hence answering. Could you please console the error and the info to see what google smtp is responding with.

Comment: Never mind. Thank anyway. I console the error. 
{[Error Self signet certificate in certificate chain ] Code : 'SEL_SIGNED_CERT_CHAIN'];

Answer (score 0):

Finally, my function is working. 
I was showing the error in console and it is

```
 {[Error Self signet certificate in certificate chain ] Code : 'SEL_SIGNED_CERT_CHAIN'];
```

I am uninstalling avast (antivirus) in my windows. Then, I can send email from localhost using nodemailer.